# Prove that the following sets are subspaces of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove if these sets are subspaces of $R^n$

$S_1 = \{x \in R^n \mid Ax = e_1\}$

$S_2 = \{x \in R^n \mid Ax \in Span(e_1)\}$

$S_3 = \{x \in R^n \mid Ax = Cx\}$

Where $e_1 \in R^n$ is the first column of canonical matrix, 
$e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

I could only figure out $S_3$, which I know is a subspace because it is basically just the kernel of $A-C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've figured out $S_1$ and $S_3$.

For $S_2$, you just need closure under addition and scalar multiplication.   So suppose $Ax_1\in\operatorname {span}e_1$ and $Ax_2\in\operatorname {span}e_1$. Then $A(x_1+x_2)=Ax_1+Ax_2\in \operatorname {span}e_1$.  And $A\alpha x_1 =\alpha Ax_1\in\operatorname {span}e_1$, since $\operatorname {span}e_1$ is a vector subspace.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the definition of $S_2$ does not make sense. For $S_1$, think about whether $0$ is in $S_1$.

Comment: Sorry I just edited $S_2$

Comment: From my understanding $0$ is not in $S_1$ because $0 \neq e_1$?

Comment: Yep and any subspace must contain the $0$ vector. So, $S_1$ is not a subspace.

Comment: $S_2$ is a subspace as you can simply check by definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition for a definition.

Comment: Thanks! Is $S_2$ a subspace because span is already a subspace so therefore Ax is? How would you formally prove this?

Comment: I think the easiest and elementary way to prove $S_2$ to be a subspace is to check the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: But what you say is exactly right if you know some abstract concept. $S_2$ is actually the "preimage" of $span(e_1)$ under $A$. i.e. $S_2 = A^{-1}(span(e_1)$. You may find the theorem here: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH423-2012A/Lect1-08web.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$0 \notin S_1$.

Note that $y \in \operatorname{sp} \{e_1\}$ **iff** $e_k^T y = 0$ for $y=2,3,...$.
Let $C=\begin{bmatrix} e_2 & \cdots & e_n \end{bmatrix}$, then
$y \in \operatorname{sp} \{e_1\}$ **iff** $y \in \ker C^T$.

We can write $S_2 = \ker (C^TA)$, hence a subspace.
(In general, if $S$ is a subspace and $A$ is linear, then $\{x | Ax \in S\} = A^{-1}(S)$ is a subspace.)

$S_3 = \ker (A-C)$, hence a subspace.